# How to map a projection class in a named SQL query

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I want this SQL query retun CustomFieldValue class, not object[], but it fails with runtime exception "Errors in named query GetCustomFields".

SQL query mapping:

```
<sql-query name="GetCustomFields">
    <return alias="cfv" class="STL.Model.CustomFieldValue, STL.Domain" />

    SELECT
    cf.NAME as {cfv.Name},
    cf.VALUE as {cfv.Name}
    ...

  </sql-query>
```

DTO:

```
 [Serializable]
        public class CustomFieldValue
        {
            public virtual string Name { get; set; }
            public virtual string Value { get; set; }
        }
```

But, remove alias, class and run something like this:

```
session.GetNamedQuery("GetCustomFields")
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(Domain.Model.CustomFieldValue)))
    .List<Domain.Model.CustomFieldValue>();
```

it works as expected. Anybody know what is wrong in the mapping ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is CustomFieldValue a mapped entity? Can you post the mapping?

Otherwise, the AliasToBean transformer is the way to go.

Comment: No, CustomFieldValue is not mapped entity, it just DTO to make SQL return typed result. 
So, as i understood, I cant return typed result if class is not mapped, correct ?

Comment: @Madman: Use the transformer then. `<return class=...` is for entities.

Comment: That's bad. Thanks for the clarification